# Recipient address required code": 400 in sending an email using Gmail API in Laravel PHP

Tags: gmail-api, email, google-contacts-api

I am trying to send an email through my system via Gmail API integration, but I receive an error i.e,

> Google_Service_Exception
>       { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "invalidArgument", "message": "Recipient address required" } ], "code": 400, "message": "Recipient address required" } }

Here is the code in Laravel:

```
$obj = new \Google_Service_Gmail_Message ();
$raw = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n\r
From: Muhammad Bilal <muhammad.bilal@dynamologic.com>\n\r
To: Umer Sheikh <umer.sheikh@dynamologic.com>\n\r
Subject: SIMPLE TEXT EMAIL\n\r
Date: Thu, 5 Mar 2020 18:45:33 +0500\n\r
Message-ID: <1234@local.machine.example>\n\r
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n\r
\n\r
NO BODY";
$raw = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($raw), '+/', '-_'), '=');
$obj->setRaw($raw);
$obj->setId('1234');
$obj->setInternalDate(null);
$obj->setLabelIds(null);

$payload = new \Google_Service_Gmail_MessagePart ();
$body = new \Google_Service_Gmail_MessagePartBody ();
$body->setData('test');
$body->setSize('1');

    $payload->setBody($body);
    $obj->setPayload($payload);
    $results = $service->users_messages->send($user, $obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved, found a sample code that worked

```
    $user = 'me';
    $strSubject = 'Test mail using GMail API' . date('M d, Y h:i:s A');
    $strRawMessage = "From: Muhammad Bilal <muhammad.bilal@dynamologic.com>\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "To: Muhammad Bilal <mb3451@yahoo.com>\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Subject: =?utf-8?B?' . base64_encode($strSubject) . "?=\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n\r\n";
    $strRawMessage .= "this <b>is a test message!\r\n";
    $mime = rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($strRawMessage), '+/', '-_'), '=');
    $msg = new \Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
    $msg->setRaw($mime);
    $service->users_messages->send("me", $msg);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you are getting is due to the fact that the `Content-Type` should be of type `message/rfc822` and **not** `text/plain`:

As mentioned in the [`Users.messages: send` documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send):

> This method supports an /upload URI and accepts uploaded media with the following characteristics:
>
> - **Maximum file size:** 35MB
> - **Accepted Media MIME types:** `message/rfc822`

Therefore the entire email message should be in an *RFC 2822 formatted base64url encoded string*.

**Reference**

- [Gmail API Send Messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send#request-body)

Comment: Updated, but still the same error

$raw = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n\r
                        From: Muhammad Bilal <muhammad.bilal@dynamologic.com>\n\r
                        To: Umer Sheikh <umer.sheikh@dynamologic.com>\n\r
                        Subject: SIMPLE TEXT EMAIL\n\r
                        Date: Thu, 5 Mar 2020 18:45:33 +0500\n\r
                        Message-ID: <1234@local.machine.example>\n\r
                        Content-Type: message/rfc822; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n\r
                        \n\r
                        NO BODY";

Comment: Hello @MuhammadBilal, what about removing the `charset=\"UTF-8\"`, are you still receiving the same error? Cheers!

Comment: Yes i am still having the same error even after removing charset=\"UTF-8\"